# iOS app submission to iTunes sourcecode has some external framework

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I wanna submit my iOS app to iTunes.I added JSon framework which is an open source framework  in my source code.Will the iTunes accept my app? As I has included code which is not created by me.Please answer if anyone knows.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as long as the framework follows the App store guidelines, ie no private apis etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since JSON Framework did not violate apple's rules.